# how to query the database without accessing the tables, correct the database but not the tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

used is c# sql vs 08 sql server 2005 express

whenever and where ever an sql select statement is used, its always like

```
select  * from tablename
```

or count statement
is alsi like

```
select count something from table name
```

for selecting or doing anything on the tables,

i would like to know which tables exits in my the database i am connected to!

so like

```
select alltablenames from database_name.
```

please guide.

Comment: Google knows this sort of stuff... http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=SQL+query+table+names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would use the `Information_Schema.Tables` & `Information_Schema.Columns` views as these are views provided by Microsoft. (Rather than using the sysobjects tables)

Comment: The reason to use them IMO is more that they're views which are part of the ANSI standard, shouldn't change between versions on a whim, and should work the same in other ANSI compliant DBs - in other words, because they're NOT Microsoft specific. sysobjects is a Microsoft specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

to list all table of database

```
USE YourDBName
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables WHERE type='u'
```

to check table exists in database or not

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM sysobjects 
    WHERE xtype='u' AND name='tablename') 
        SELECT 'tablename exists.' 
ELSE 
        SELECT 'tablename does not exist.'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the names of the tables in an SQL Server database:

```
select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U'
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://database.ittoolbox.com/documents/finding-table-names-in-sql-18556 - simple queries for all table names and all columns for a given table.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
EXEC sp_tables
```